# How do I retrieve multiple rows when using an inner WHERE IN clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a `customers` table with columns `zip` and `cust_id` that contains every zip code for each customer.
I have a `zip_state` reference table with columns `zip` and `state` that contains every zip code in each state.

What I would like to do is have a list of states for each customer - something like:

```
states      cust_id
--------- ---------
AL,TX,FL        112
WA,VA           113
FL,CA           114
```

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( state, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY state ) states, '112' cust_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM zip_state WHERE zip IN (
        SELECT zip FROM customers WHERE cust_id = '112'));
```

...which renders:

```
states      cust_id
--------- ---------
AL,TX,FL        112
```

Because of the WHERE IN clause, I'm only able to list states for one customer.
How can I modify the query such that I get the desired result set as per above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(state, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY state ) states, cust_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cust_id, state
      FROM zip_state z JOIN
           customers c
           on c.zip = z.zip
     ) zc
GROUP BY cust_id;
```